# How to Dependency inject Data Access Layer which takes database settings in it's constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, data-access-layer

I wrote a simple Data access interface with generic CRUD operations so that every database repository has to implement this interface. For now I implemented this interface for one database say SQL. This SQL implementation of the database takes database settings(connection string and other details) as parameter in it's constructor.

See below code:

```
namespace MyDataAccessInterfaces
{
   public interface IDataAccess
   {
    read();
    create();
    update();
    delete();
   }
}

namespace MyDataAccessImplementations
{

   public class SQLAccess
   {
     SQLAccess(Settings settings){
     //do something to get DB context
      }

   //some properties here 

    read(){//some code
          }
    create(){//some code
          }
    update(){//some code
          }
    delete(){//some code
          }
   }
}
```

Now I want to dependency inject this into a Service controller. I'm looking at constructor dependency injection here. If I pass SQL implementation as dependency in controller constructor as below and add this in startup class->ConfigureServie method, how to pass it's settings?

```
public class HomeController : APIController
{
    private readonly IDataAccess _dataAccess;

    public HomeController(IDataAccess dataAccess)
    {
        _dataAccess= dataAccess;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //do something and set result
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Below is my ConfigureService method in startup.cs class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add application services.
       services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, SQLAccess>();
}
```

Question is, How do I pass the constructor parameters and property values in API's Configure Service method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add application services.
       services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, SQLAccess>(opt=> { new SQLAccess(new 
       Settings(){ 
           //Set Settings object properties here

       }); 
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!. Can you point me to microsoft or any other documentation where this is specified/explained. Also In the above code, How can I make the SQLAccess singleton?

Comment: I believe SQLAccess is singleton. To check put a breakpoint on the line new SQLAccess and see if it hits breakpoint everytime you method on SQLAccess or only one time.

services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, SQLAccess>(opt=> { 
       new SQLAccess(new Settings(){ 
           //Set Settings object properties here

       });

[link](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-di-deep-dive)

Comment: That is in API start up class. Can we make SQLAccess  implementation of the interface itself singleton?